# GCD timer never fires

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a bare single-view iOS app with the following in the `-viewDidLoad` of the view:

```
dispatch_queue_t q_default;
q_default = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, q_default); //run event handler on the default global queue
dispatch_time_t now = dispatch_walltime(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, now, 30ull*NSEC_PER_SEC, 5000ull);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    printf("test\n");
});
dispatch_resume(timer);
```

This is taken directly from the docs (except for a simplified `printf()` argument).  The block is never executed--can someone tell me why??

**Additional Information**

I was trying this in a larger app to no avail.  I then backed out to the barebones app, tried with ARC both on and off, tried this code in `-appDidFinishLaunching...`, all with no luck.  I can surround this code with `NSLog`s, both of which are printed.  I've checked `timer`--it is not `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the problem was that I'd lost my reference to `timer` when the surrounding scope was destroyed.  Changing `timer` to an ivar instead of an automatic variable fixed things...

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation of [dispatch_source_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_source_create):

> Dispatch sources are created in a suspended state. After creating the
>   source and setting any desired attributes (for example, the handler or
>   the context), your application must call dispatch_resume to begin
>   event delivery.

So your timer never fires because it's suspended. To end its suspension you need to call [dispatch_resume](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_resume).

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I am calling `dispatch_resume`, though (just missed it in the copy-paste).  Thanks--I've edited my question.